# C# & DevExpress Reporting : Dynamic parameters

Tags: c#, parameters, devexpress, report

I'm sorry for the hard-to-understand title

Normally, to work with Devexpress Report Parameters, we'll have to :

- Create parameters in Parameter Panel (Field list)
- Assign parameters when calling report, or fill-in parameters'value directly before previewing/printing

But now, we want to make it simple and dynamic, the idea is to pass a object that contains all possible report paramteters, someth like this :

```
public class ReportParameters
{
    public string Title{get;set;}
    public DateTime ReportDate{get;set;}
    // ..... much more 
}
```

And on the report, all we need to do is assign the corresponding property of ReportParameters, then something like this :

```
XtraReport1 report1 = new XtraReport1(); 
ReportParameters rpara = new ReportParameters();
rpara.Title = "SomeTitle"; 
rpara.ReportDate = DateTime.Today.Date(); 
report1.ParaObjectSource = rpara ; // parameters source
report1.DataSource = reportDataSource; // data (detail) source 
report1.ShowPreview();
```

please note the **ParaObjectSource** is something I made up to illustrate my idea

My question is, how can i pass additional object(s) into a Report besides the datasource object ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just add whatever you want in your `XtraReport` descendant class.
Here is example:

```
public class XtraReport1 : XtraReport
{
    public XtraReport1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ReportParameters ParaObjectSource {get; set;}

    protected override void OnBeforePrint(PrintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnBeforePrint(e);

        //Create parameters for report from your ParaObjectSource 
    }
}
```